# What's best way to host large amount of content in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, storage

I have one application which consumes over 40GB content of xml files. Each file is about 40 ~ 100KB. 
Today there is a tool to generate new files or update existing files and then publish them to on-premise servers. 
Now I'm moving my application to Azure. Because I have no way to make any changes on the publishing tool, I can build another tool to upload all the content to Azure blob storage and sync blob storage with on-premise content.

Is there other way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can check `azcopy`. I've never used it but many colleague are using it to dealing with large data between on-premise and cloud.

Comment: azcopy looks like a good tool to copy files to blob. Besides of blob storage, any other options to store large amount of files in Azure?

Comment: also powershell is a nifty tooling here, even in combo with Azure Automation .. jsut saying :-)

Comment: I'm asking for other options other than blob storage is that it's not convenient compared to store in local disk.

Comment: Because content keep updating, I need to monitor the whole 40GB file directory. there are millions of files. what's the most efficient technique to monitor the file changes?

Comment: I'm asking for other options other than blob storage is that it's not convenient compared to store in local disk. It's making migration really painful. Today all servers have local copy of those content. is there a way to make the Azure migration seamless?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Storage Explorer or Azure Explorer from Cerebrata

http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-explorer/introduction

https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've tried both. like cerebrata more. I'm more looking for automated solution here.

Comment: use azure automation and powershell then instead, or call the rest api. Powershell is the easiest since you can create scheduled jobs from withing your network and keep it running in the background. all you need is the Azure Powershell cmdlets and your good to go

Comment: I'm thinking to have the tool to monitor directory. when there are changes, upload the new/updated files to blob using rest api. But not sure if there is efficient and reliable technique to monitor such huge file directory. I'm using windows server 2012.